# Bypassing ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python

How can I bypass the ZeroDivisionError and allow the program to continue whilst noting the 0 value?

```
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  ptot=0
  ntot=0
  for pchar in "HKR":
    pchartotal=split[1].count(pchar)
    #print pchartotal
    ptot+=pchartotal
  for nchar in "DE":
    nchartotal=split[1].count(nchar)
    #print nchartotal
    ntot+=nchartotal
  print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `try-except` :

```
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  ptot=0
  ntot=0
  for pchar in "HKR":
    pchartotal=split[1].count(pchar)
    #print pchartotal
    ptot+=pchartotal
  for nchar in "DE":
    nchartotal=split[1].count(nchar)
    #print nchartotal
    ntot+=nchartotal
  try:
    print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
  except ZeroDivisionError :
    print "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero"
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
```

to

```
try:
    print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print err
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try{..} except{..}` block

```
try:
    print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
except ZeroDivisionError:
   print 'divide by zero'
```

[Handling Exceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
try:
    print (1/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ("Yo that's divide by zero")

print ("Done cya")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just test and substitute the value when detecting a zero divisor;

```
print ('NA' if not ntot else float(ptot)/float(ntot))
```